# Group by a variable in R and then run dplyr case_when

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, case-when

I want to make a new variable for every group in my dataset 
I'm using this code:

```
 data <- data  %>%
  group_by(Set_Number , Set_score) %>%
  mutate(test = case_when(
    lag(data$Serves_In_Fault) == "Serve In" ~ "Second Serve" ,
    lag(data$Serves_In_Fault) == "Fault" ~ "First Serve"
  )
)
```

although, this gives me an error

> Error: Column `test` must be length 93 (the group size) or one, not
>   164

I want a value for every row in the dataset not for every group. Please help.

Comment: Don't use `data$Serves_In_Fault`, just `Serves_In_Fault`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you're qualifying `Servers_In_Fault` with `data$` in front of it. That way, you're accessing a new copy of the entire structure of `data`, not the `data` structure that's being processed. You're already within `data`, so you don't need to do it. When you do a `group_by()`, you're dealing subgroups of the data frame, one at a time. So when you try to process a subgroup of size 93, and you throw at it a new copy of `data`, with its full 164 rows, sizes don't match. Just remove the `data$` within the pipes and you'll be fine.